# How to implement a small Dropdown to UIButton e.g. to select a currency in Swift 4 and iOS 11?

Tags: drop-down-menu, swift4

I tried to use Dropper to get a small Dropdown menu when a UIButton was tapped, e.g. to select a currency, but the `DropperSelectedRow()` was never called so I can't use its. It won't work in case of no support for swift 4 I think.

How can I implement a small and simple dropdown, which Pod should I use?
I need it for a iOS 11 App using Swift 4 and Xcode 9.

[image: example for the wanted dropdown menu]

Comment: What OS is this for? Update your question with what you tried. Clearly explain the issues you are having.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all:**

The author of Dropper said: add

`extension ViewController: DropperDelegate`

when he probably wanted to say: add

`extension UIViewController: DropperDelegate`

see the difference between ViewController and UIViewController?

**Alternatively** You can use it in your view controller as delegate:

```
class yourViewController: UIViewController, DropperDelegate {
...
@objc func DropperSelectedRow(_ path: IndexPath, contents: String) {
        print(path)
        print(contents)
    }
}
```

Don't forget `@objc` in front of the delegate method

**Secondly:**

for creating a small menu, initiate it as follow:

```
let dropper = Dropper(width: 80, height: 200)
```

change width and height as you like.

**Thirdly:**

It works fine with Swift 4.0